# PayPal Pro NVP API Error Localization

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

I am creating an english and french website that will be using paypal for payment processing. 
I have all of the PayPal API working properly, and currently I am just outputting any error messages to the user (L_LONGMESSAGEX). However this is always english, is there a way to output the error messages as french?

I saw a LOCALECODE parameter but that seems to be something else.

Or am I going to have to setup my own lookup table based off the error codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This is not possible.
The PayPal API error messages are intended for your use only; you're supposed to properly handle these exceptions within your own application, and output a more meaningful message to the buyer.

(For example; "L_LONGMESSAGE0=This transaction has already been approved" means nothing to your buyers. Yet "This transaction has been processed previously. Did you order twice? Give our support team a call if you have any questions regarding your order!" is a lot clearer.)

Comment: To add: LOCALECODE affects the locale (and thus also the language) used to display the checkout to the buyer in.

Comment: By the way: PayPal Adaptive Payments does support this with the `errorLanguage` parameter, but I still suggest not to display any PayPal error messages externally.